# FileUploadUI валидация файлов yii2

Tags: php, jquery, yii2, jquery-ui, fileupload

Использую виджет https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-file-upload-widget 
для загрузки файлов различного типа. Не могу понять где я могу конкретно перечислить форматы которые возможно загружать?Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В виджетах:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения],

список возможных значений - http://htmlbook.ru/html/value/mime

И в модели прописать в rules нужные типы:

`['image', 'file', 'extensions' => 'png, jpg, jpeg']`

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html#file